# Java allow to run private method? Can someone explain why?

Tags: java

Someone asked me if he can run private base function. I told him that of course it is not possible (apart from trick of relection).
But what the hell is this:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        A a = new B();
        a.doSomething();

        B b = new B();
        b.doSomethingMore();
    }

   static class A {
        private void doSomething(){
            System.out.println("something");
        }
    }

    static class B extends A{
        public void doSomethingMore(){
            ((A)this).doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not clear about the code?

Comment: Your method is private to the class `MyClass`. It can be called from any code inside `MyClass`.

Comment: `private` access level class YES https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: Your inner classes A and B are in the same scope. If you remove B from MyClass, the visibility will be hidden, and you cannot call the private method.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this is a duplicate, but I wouldn't call it a duplicate of [this marked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989494/why-am-i-able-to-call-private-method) (and certainly not of [this PHP question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27066518/why-can-you-call-a-private-method-from-outside-of-the-object-scope)!).

Comment: @rockfarkas - I already did. :-) (Note that the PHP question had been mistagged [tag:java] as well as [tag:php], I fixed that as well...)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/what-is-the-difference-between-public-protected-package-private-and-private-in Public, protected, no modifier, private

Answer (score 2):

`A` and `B` are both members of `MyClass`, so they have access to all of `MyClass`'s private features, and to each other's private features; and `MyClass` has access to all of their private features. More in the [Java nested classes tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

Now, if they **weren't** nested classes, then naturally `MyClass` wouldn't have access to their private features, and they wouldn't wouldn't have access to each others' private features. For instance, this won't compile:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        A a = new B();
        a.doSomething();            // error: doSomething() has private access in A

        B b = new B();
        b.doSomethingMore();
    }
}

class A {
    private void doSomething(){
        System.out.println("something");
    }
}

class B extends A{
    public void doSomethingMore(){
        ((A)this).doSomething();    // error: doSomething() has private access in A
    }
}
```

Comment: I can understood MyClass having access to his childs, but B having access to A's doSomething have no sense at all. Well thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Zixav - I get why you'd think that. :-) But the point of nested classes, the design philosophy behind them, is that they're really *part of* the class they're in. So **all** of the private stuff is shared between them. (But I could see the design decision going either way, frankly. This is just the way it went, 24+ years ago... :-) )